# Get the first occurrence of number from a text with characters before or after it

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Assuming i have a string

```
$string1 = aed19209afg92019
$string2 = asd2919291029920192iig19202lm
$string3 = defcka090slalso01
$string4 = a1b2
$string5 = 2b
$string6 = dexter1
```

how can i retrieve all numbers only with the a char as a first occurrence?

desired output:

```
19209
2919291029920192
090
1
2
1
```

Here is my current code:

```
$pattern = '/\w[0-9]\w/'
$hasMatch = preg_match($pattern, $details, $returnMatch);
if($hasMatch){
    return $returnMatch[0];
}
```

unfortunately it returns both numbers and string.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Have a look at regex. There's plenty of questions relating to it on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+only+numbers+php

Comment: i know there's a lot of regex questions, but i need to get only the first occurance

Comment: `echo preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", "asd2919291029920192iig19202lm");` or `echo preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $mString);`

Comment: Perhaps, `preg_match('~[a-z]\K\d+~i', $s, $match)`.

Comment: hello Antonis, so this sample code mean that it will only get the first occurrence?

Comment: Oh my fault, no the above code is just to show numbers.

Comment: Hello everyone, can you post your answers so that i could mark them if I have proven them correct?

Comment: Is your string above a single multiline string input? Or are these `aed19209afg92019`, `asd2919291029920192iig19202lm`, etc. are standalone strings?

Comment: standalone strings Wiktor

Comment: Does [this](https://ideone.com/mglLEd) work?

Comment: hello Wiktor, yeah it works. But what if there are no characters in front of the string? hey could you post your answer here, I will mark it as answer you already answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the first match with a regex in PHP, you need to use `preg_match`. The pattern you need is

```
'~[a-z]\K\d+~i'
```

It will match an ASCII letter (with `[a-z]`, the `~i` makes it case insensitive), drop it from the match (with `\K`), and will grab 1+ digits right after it. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZcym1/1).

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/mglLEd):

```
$strs = array("aed19209afg92019", "asd2919291029920192iig19202lm", "defcka090slalso01", "a1b2", "2b", "dexter1");
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    if (preg_match('~[a-z]\K\d+~i', $s, $m))
    {
        echo $m[0] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Maybe I need to look at the cheat sheet of Regex

Comment: BTW, you may also use a lookbehind here - `'~(?<=[a-z])\d+~i'`, or a capturing group - `'~[a-z](\d+)~i'`